# Python overwriting array when returned from function

Tags: python, arrays, artificial-intelligence, overwrite

For an Artificial Intelligence assingment I'm trying to get 4 separate arrays by sending an array into a generate function as a return value. When sending array 1 it works normally. But when sending array 2, 3, and 4 it will overwrite the previous generated array. The output at for the last array, array4 is at this moment:

```
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', 'G', '☐', 'G', '#']
['#', '☐', 'P', '•', '#']
['#', 'P', '•', 'P', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
```

The ideal output for array4 is:

```
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', 'G', '•', 'G', '#']
['#', '☐', '☐', '•', '#']
['#', 'P', '•', '•', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
```

Below is my full Python code:

```
def solver():
matrix = [['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], ['#', 'G', '•', 'G', '#'], ['#', '☐', '☐', '•', '#', ],
         ['#', '•', 'P', '•', '#'], ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
countx = 0
county = 0
cordp = []
for x in matrix:
    county += 1
    for y in x:
        countx += 1
        if y == 'P':
            cordp = [countx, county]
    countx = 0
    print(x)
# nieuwe stap
    # wat is huidige positie
cordp[0], cordp[1] = cordp[1]-1, cordp[0]-1

n = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, 0,-1)
e = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, 1,0)
s = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, 0,1)
w = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, -1,0)

for x in n:
    print(x)

def gen_matrix(matrixnew, cordp, x, y):
print (x)
print(y)
if matrixnew[cordp[0]+y][cordp[1]+x] == '☐':
    if matrixnew[cordp[0]+y*2][cordp[1]+x*2] == '#':
        print("ik kan doos niet verplaatsen")
    else:
        print("IK HEB EEN BOX en kan deze verplaatsen")
        matrixnew[cordp[0]+y*2][cordp[1]+x*2] = '☐'
        matrixnew[cordp[0]+y][cordp[1]+x] = 'P'
        matrixnew[cordp[0]][cordp[1]] = '•'
elif matrixnew[cordp[0]+y][cordp[1]+x] == '•':
    print("ik heb een bolletje")
    matrixnew[cordp[0]+y][cordp[1]+x] = 'P'
    matrixnew[cordp[0]][cordp[1]] = '•'
elif matrixnew[cordp[0]+y][cordp[1]+x] == '#':
    print("ik heb een muur")

return matrixnew
solver()
```

Comment: python works by reference, so it's likely (as your code is somewhat unclear) you are re-using a reference. Try passing a copy of the matrix to gen_matrix instead, and then each should be updated independently. https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul pointed out in the comments, you're overwriting your matrix since python passes lists by reference rather than by value.

The fix is to copy the matrices before modifying them.

We can copy a 2d matrix, i.e. a list of lists, like this:

```
matrix_copy = [list(row) for row in original_matrix]
```

so we can replace this

```
n = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, 0,-1)
e = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, 1,0)
s = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, 0,1)
w = gen_matrix(matrix, cordp, -1,0)
```

with this

```
n = gen_matrix([list(row) for row in matrix], cordp, 0,-1)
e = gen_matrix([list(row) for row in matrix], cordp, 1,0)
s = gen_matrix([list(row) for row in matrix], cordp, 0,1)
w = gen_matrix([list(row) for row in matrix], cordp, -1,0)
```

to give `gen_matrix` a new copy of the matrix for each run.